# Question about synchronisation using threads

Tags: java

I do not understand why the output of my code is still messed up. I expect that after Producer write will always come Consumer read and never Producer write after Producer write for example. Especially because I have synchronized the code and added methods wait and notify which should do that. Can someone please help me out as soon as possible. Thanks in advance :)

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IntCell cell = new UnsynchronizedIntCell();
        Thread prod1 = new Thread(new IntProducer(1, cell), "Producer 1");
        Thread cons1 = new Thread(new IntConsumer(1, cell), "Consumer 1");

        prod1.start();
        cons1.start();
    }

public class IntConsumer implements Runnable {
    private IntCell cell;

    public IntConsumer(int nr, IntCell cellArg) {
        this.cell = cellArg;
    }

    public void run() {
        int val;
        do {
            synchronized(this) {
                val = cell.getValue();
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() 
                        + ": " + val + " read");
                // sleep for a random interval
                try {
                    Thread.sleep((int) (Math.random() * 3000));
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } while (val != -1);

        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": end");
    }
}

public class IntProducer implements Runnable {
    private int nr;
    private IntCell cell;

    public IntProducer(int nrArg, IntCell cellArg) {
        this.nr = nrArg;
        this.cell = cellArg;
    }

    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            synchronized(this){
                int val = 10 * nr + i;
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() 
                        + ": " + val + " written");
                cell.setValue(val);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep((int) (Math.random() * 3000));
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() 
                + ": end");
    }
}

public interface IntCell {
    public void setValue(int val);
    public int getValue();
}

public class UnsynchronizedIntCell implements IntCell {
    private int value = 0;
    private boolean empty = true;
    private int count = 0;



    public synchronized void setValue(int valueArg) {
        while(!empty) {
            try {
                wait();
            }catch(InterruptedException e) {

            }
        }

        this.value = valueArg;
        empty = false;
        notifyAll();
    }

    public synchronized int getValue() {
        if(count == 10) {
            return -1;
        }
        while(empty) {
            try {
                wait();
            }catch(InterruptedException e) {

            }
        }       
        empty = true;
        count = count +1;
        notifyAll();
        return value;
    }
}

// OUTPUT ...there is read read and written written each once
Producer 1: 10 written
Consumer 1: 10 read
Producer 1: 11 written
Consumer 1: 11 read
Producer 1: 12 written
Consumer 1: 12 read
Producer 1: 13 written
Consumer 1: 13 read
Producer 1: 14 written
Consumer 1: 14 read
Producer 1: 15 written
Producer 1: 16 written
Consumer 1: 15 read
Consumer 1: 16 read
Producer 1: 17 written
Consumer 1: 17 read
Producer 1: 18 written
Producer 1: 19 written
Consumer 1: 18 read
Consumer 1: 19 read
Producer 1: end
Consumer 1: -1 read
Consumer 1: end
```

Comment: But it's synchronized, isn't it? Your producer writes 2 times in a row, but the consumer then reads all the two values, not only the last one. If it wasn't sync'd, the producer would write 2 values and the consumer then will extract the last value.

Comment: Yes thats true, so there is no interference that some values are not read or written. Indeed all values are read and written, but the order is messed up. I want first one producer value, then one consumer value. I thought this is exactly what wait and notiyAll does. Can someone pls explain whats wrong then here?